# How do the currents induced by the E-field and H- field flow? Which of the two currents induced by E or H has the larger amplitude?

Tags: antenna, emc, transmitter, shielding

I came across this problem for an exam preparation question, which I am struggling to answer.

Consider a sphere made of thin metal, with a radius of 1 m, at 20 km distance from an AM transmitter operating at 1 MHz. The alternating current in the transmitter tower flows vertically. The amplitudes of the E- and H-fields at 20 km from the transmitter are called E0 and H0.

1. How do the currents induced by the E-field and H- field flow on the sphere?

I assume the currents induced by the E-field flow around the equator of the sphere, parallel to it. The currents induced by the H-field flow from pole to pole, perpendicular to the equator of the sphere.
2) Which of the two currents induced by E or H has the larger amplitude?

I assume that the amplitude of the induced currents depends on various factors such as the strength of the electric and magnetic field.
3) In which region of the sphere are these currents flowing in the same direction, strengthening each other?

With a wall thickness of say 1 mm this sphere (if without slits) shields quite well at 1 MHz. Unfortunately, manufacturing problems make it necessary to construct the sphere in two parts; two half spheres of aluminum. Because of the oxide layer on the aluminum surface the shielding currents cannot cross over from one half
sphere to the other; we have a narrow, continuous slit between the two half spheres.

I assume the currents induced by the electric field generally have larger amplitudes. The regions where these currents strengthen each other are along the edges of the narrow, continuous slit between the two half spheres, where the induced currents cannot cross over and flow in the same direction around the edges.

I tried to answer everything doubtful, I would like to get inputs regarding my answer. Does someone know any study link to understand E and H fields better?

Comment: Hints - 20 km distance is far field, so E and H incident have the impedance of free space ratio, 377 ohms. If you've cut a circumferential slit round it, then frequency needs to be known, as you've constructed an antenna. Polairisation also needs to be known, with respect to the slit orientation. At wavelengths of the order of sphere size, this is extremely important. If you had a conducting sphere, you would know the field inside is zero, so you might be able to do this by the method of images.